# NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error: does not respect POSIX permissions

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have some code that checks for the existence of a file and, if it is present, deletes it. The problem is, I am unable to get it to fail even if the file should not be writeable. My code looks like:

```
if([theManager fileExistsAtPath:savingAs isDirectory:&destIsDir])
   {
   BOOL itemRemoved=[theManager removeItemAtPath:savingAs error:&err];
   if(!itemRemoved)
      {
      // why?
      NSAlert *rebuildAlert=[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Error removing item" 
        defaultButton:nil alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil
        informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@",[err localizedDescription]];
      [rebuildAlert runModal];
      proceed=NO;
      }
   }
```

Even if I set ownership to root:wheel and mode to 000 (i.e. not readable, writeable or executable by anyone) the file is still silently deleted. The account I'm running this from is a user account with Admin privileges but even so, being able to kill files owned by root doesn't seem very safe. The only way to throw an error is to lock the file using `chflags uchg` *filename*. I have also implemented (as a stub for now) the `fileManager:shouldRemoveItemAtPath:` delegate method where I could check permissions if necessary. The problem is that returning `NO` from this method does not cause `removeItemAtPath:` to return an error. Re-checking with `fileExistsAtPath:` seems cumbersome. Finally, there doesn't seem to be a simple method of disambiguating which instance of `NSFileManager` is issuing the call to `removeItemAtPath:` in the delegate method. Typically these instances are transitory objects so their id's are not valid for any significant length of time. I could sub-class NSFileManager and add a tag instance variable but that seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

In summary:

1) is it correct behaviour for removeItemAtPath to ignore files it does not own?

2) disallowing file deletion in the delegate method is not communicated back to the caller of `removeItemAtPath`

3) determining which invocation is calling the delegate method is hard

Comment: This sounds like standard POSIX behaviour. Try the same action, but instead of using `NSFileManager`, use `rm` at the command line. You'll still be able to delete the file.

Comment: Yes, I was just unsure to what extent the Cocoa file management functions act as a wrapper round POSIX filesystem calls. I guess in the end `removeFileAtPath:` calls `unlink(2)`. I'm still not sure what to do about communication between the delegate and the caller. For now I am subclassing `NSFileManager`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct behavior.  Erasing a file does not require read access to the file, only the directory containing it. Think of a directory as a list of files, and erasing a file as simply removing it from that list, and it will all make sense.

Comment: I know this is standard UNIX behaviour (and one I've never been very fond of,) but it struck me as a bit 'un-Mac-like'.